# using big-bang and on-tick

Tags: scheme, racket

So I am trying to make a program that grows the image "HI" using big-bang. I have it placed in the center of the canvas. I want the text size to start at 1 and stop growing when the size reaches 80.  I've added the on-tick but it still won't start at 1 and grow. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

edit-

```
    (require 2htdp/image)
    (require 2htdp/universe)

    (define word "HELLO WORLD" )

    (define (draw-world world )
      (place-image (text word world  "olive")
                   240 210
                   (empty-scene 500 300)))


         (define (next t)
  (cond [(>= (draw-world t) 80) t]
        [else (+ t 1)]))

    (big-bang 1
              (on-tick add1)
              (to-draw draw-world)
              (stop-when zero?))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things. The most important one is in `draw-world` 
where you draw a text of size 11. If you instead draw a text of size `world` then your text will have the same size as the current world.

```
(text word world "olive")
```

After fixing that bug, you will immediately spot the next thing to fix.

Update:

```
(define (stop? a-world)
  (<= a-world 80))
```

Comment: I got it to work. All I need to do now is make it stop growing when it reaches the text size of 80. I am guessing I need to change the last part of the big-bang. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you in Fundies 1 by any chance? @JerryLynch

Comment: @JerryLynch: do you know why `stop-when` is useful?

Comment: dyoo, yes. i tried the opposite.  big-bang 80, sub1, stop-when zero?. and it stopped.  now making it stop at 80 is what is dificult.

Comment: @JerryLynch  I added a `stop?` function, you can try out.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)

(define WORD "HELLO WORLD" )

(define (main x)
  (big-bang x
          (on-tick next)        ; World -> World
          (to-draw draw-world)  ; World -> Image
          (stop-when stop?)))   ; World -> Boolean


; World -> World
; Gives the next world
(define (next world)
  (cond [(>= world 80) world]
        [else (+ world 1)]))

; World -> Image
; Draw the current world
(define (draw-world world )
  (place-image (text WORD world  "olive")
               240 210
               (empty-scene 500 300)))

; World -> Boolean
; Check if this is the last world
(define (stop? world)
  (= world 80))

(main 1)
```